# UPS does not get charged

Tags: ups

My 4 year old UPS (uninterrupted power supply) hasn't been getting charged for the last few months. I have searched a lot on Google but haven't found any solution to make it charge again.

How do I fix my UPS

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace the battery/batteries. Batteries don't live forever, and UPSes in general kill batteries faster than some other services, due to cost-cutting in the charger design and/or focussing on getting the battery recharged as fast as possible after an outage.

UPS batteries usually need to be replaced on no more than a 3-year cycle, in my experience. Life may be improved somewhat if you have the space (and lack of children) to keep the batteries near but not in the UPS case, as many UPSes run hot, and heat is not good for battery life.

Warning/note - if you don't buy generic batteries, you may find that "new replacement batteries from your UPS brand" cost **more** than a new UPS. Shop wisely.

Comment: how to replace the batteries of an UPS

Comment: @D.Misal, RTFM.  There's too much variation between UPSs to give instructions here.

Comment: @D.Misal That is impossible to say. There are too many UPS makers and models and variants. Also, it would have to be a new question. On that question, you would need to specify the model, brand and, at least, provide more information.

Comment: @Mark I am using Intex UPS

Comment: Additional Warning/Note:  If you do buy generic batteries, make sure you're getting what you think you are.  My experience with getting new batteries for several 1300VA UPSes (multiple brands) is that there are plenty of un-ethical resellers who will list batteries with significantly smaller capacities (amp hours) than the OEM ones for use with larger UPSes.  Presumably they'd work; but you'd end up with only the backup capacity of a 1000VA UPS instead of a 1300/1500VA model.  Equivalent sized generic batteries were never more than a 5-10% cheaper than an OEM replacement.

Comment: My experience in shopping for 4.5AH and 7 AH 12V SLA batteries (by size and voltage, not by "someone said they were a replacement for UPS XXX") was that I could get the same capacity for less than half the OEM "sucker" price. YMMV.